# AWS IoT Core createTopicRule unable to set trigger point for lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I created one lambda function using nodejs that is responsible to create iotTopicRule. It is able to create the rule in aws iot core and also showing the action lambda function in rule created but it is not showing that rule as a trigger point in lambda function due to which that rule is not getting triggered the lambda function. also if I click on edit rule and save it without making any changes it is showing the rule as a trigger point in lambda function.

here is my code:

```
await iot.createTopicRule({
    ruleName: 'myRuleName',
    topicRulePayload: {
        actions: [{
            lambda: { functionArn: ruleActionArn }
        }],
        awsIotSqlVersion: '2016-03-23',
        sql: `MySQLStatement`
    }
}).promise();
```

Note : functionArn and SQL Statement are correct